# d3.js force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am using d3 force directed layout to draw a connected node graph. Everytime the number of nodes changes, I want to show the entire graph with smaller size. For this I am using scale property of SVG. However, I am not able to fix the position of the graph.

Below is the code I am using:

```
svg.attr("transform",
"translate(0,0) scale(" + bh/diameter + ")");
```

svg --> is the main SVG element that holds my graph 
bh --> width and height of my svg element 
diameter --> is of the force graph

Comment: What do you mean by the position of the graph? The position of the svg? Or of the nodes in the graph? Or do you mean the scale is not working?